# Ftp upload with Powershell vs FileZilla

Tags: ftp, powershell, upload, filezilla

With a 210MB file, using a script like below takes a little over 10 minutes with Powershell:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$uri1 = New-Object System.Uri($Ftp2)
$webclient.UploadFile($uri1, $File2)
```

However, using FileZilla, it takes under 2 minutes for the same file.

Is FileZilla optimized?  Can I improve the Powershell call somehow?

I prefer to use PS as I have scripts that upload multi-GB files...

Comment: Have you tired ensuring that it's not (trying) to use a proxy?  You can use `$webclient.proxy = null` to disable proxy usage.  Also, have you tried using the [.Net FTPWebRequest class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) instead?

Comment: haven't done either...will try both...thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the proxy = null didn't change the timing, however, using FTPWebRequest did the trick.